# TableView Unable to get DATA which are scrolled up or down

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, xcode7

Whenever I try to get data from a cell it returns empty value, however I found that I'm unable to read data from cells that are Scrolled Up/Down of TableView

here is image clearing my situation
[image]

Here is the code I'm using for saving data:

```
  NSMutableArray *arrTmp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i = 0; i<[tblView numberOfRowsInSection:0]; i++){
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        FUCellView  *cell         = [tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        UITextField *tfNo         = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:i + 100];
        UIButton    *btnTime      = (UIButton    *)[cell viewWithTag:i + 200];
        UITextField *tfVisit      = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:i + 300];
        UIButton    *btnProvider  = (UIButton    *)[cell viewWithTag:i + 400];

        NSMutableDictionary *theDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        if([tfNo.text length] > 0 && tfNo.text != nil){
            NSString* str = [tfNo.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
            [theDictionary setObject:str forKey:@"number"];
        }
        else{
            [theDictionary setObject:@"" forKey:@"number"];
        }
        if([btnTime.titleLabel.text length] > 0 && btnTime.titleLabel.text != nil){
            NSString* str = [btnTime.titleLabel.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
            [theDictionary setObject:str forKey:@"time"];
        }
        else{
            [theDictionary setObject:@"" forKey:@"time"];
        }
        if([tfVisit.text length] > 0 && tfVisit.text != nil){
            NSString* str = [tfVisit.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
            [theDictionary setObject:str forKey:@"visit_type"];
        }
        else{
            [theDictionary setObject:@"" forKey:@"visit_type"];
        }
        if([btnProvider.titleLabel.text length] > 0 && btnProvider.titleLabel.text != nil){
            NSString* str = [btnProvider.titleLabel.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
            [theDictionary setObject:str forKey:@"provider"];
        }
        else{
            [theDictionary setObject:@"" forKey:@"provider"];
            NSLog(@"ProviderELse");
        }
         [arrTmp addObject:theDictionary];
```

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you, you should keep ur data somewhere else(u might have a model with data right?) and then appropriate to model set (in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`) `UITableView`. There is no need to set or get data direct from `UITableView`. Please read official documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/)

[Here](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/) is nice lesson about Table View. Good luck.

Comment: for saving Data im using Arrays wich got erased Probably often time so i found this approach is easier for me , has a drawback . ok will think upon your Suggestion

Comment: Please read about MVC(model - view - controller) pattern, your view should not keep any data,only show it,and view can not direct interact with model only thru controller.If your array often erased try to keep original version of this array in some kind of singleton(design pattern) and in controller work with copy of this array.

Answer (score 0):

UITableview is reusing  the cells. So you can't get the values in for loop. This will return nil.

A better approach is to use a data model for storing the values.

For example: Create a data Model . Add some properties to it. And load cells with these properties. Now only you need to update the model object properties.

Store these model objects in an array.

Finally you can have the data ready at any time.

Comment: i'm not familiar with Core Data , will try to implement your approach using two or more array's , Thanks you for replying

Comment: Thanks you @Abdul Yasin